# DBContext doesn't save changes the first time around

Tags: c#, database, savechanges, ultrawingrid

As stated in the title I am trying to save changes. For that I am using an ultragrid that is connected to my database. The weird thing is that if I try to save any change in ultragrid the first time (by pressing the btnSave) it doesn't save the changes, but any subsequent change, after reopening the childform, gets saved. What could be the Problem?

This is my Code

```cs
private Context _context;

public ChildForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _context = new Context();
}

private void Module_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _context.Module.Load();
    ModuleBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Module.Local.ToBindingList();
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ultraGrid.ActiveCell.Activated)
    {
        ultraGrid1.PerformAction(
            Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.Dispose();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: When save changes is called the first time is there anything in the ChangeTracker? Does this change the 2nd time when the save works properly?

Comment: Is the load method being executed?  It may not be registered as an event.  You also shouldn't Dispose the context unless you plan to reconnect the _context to the database every time you do a query.  The _context has links to the database that has to be retained.  The context should be in the main code and passed to the form so you are not reconnecting to the database every time you use the form.

Comment: I don't know how, but the problem solved itself by simply putting "_context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();" befor the "_context.SaveChanges();" Methode.
So thanks to @TheEvilMetal I guess ^^'

Comment: So seeing a "button_click" code .. in the same place as "dbContext.SaveChanges()"...is a red flag that you do not have the basic "layers" in your application.  Please take time to review this concept.  internet-search for "c# software layers"  here is a starting point : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-net-3-tier-architecture/